# C# - How to call an api inside another api with windows impersonation?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to access SharePoint using impersonation, but I'm getting a 401 return. 
web api is debugged from user1 account with spn

```
setspn -A HTTP/localhost DOMAIN\user1
setspn -A HTTPS/localhost DOMAIN\user1
```

SharePoint work from user2 with spn and enabled ssl, win auth and Negotiate provider.

```
setspn -A HTTP/SPServer DOMAIN\user2
setspn -A HTTPS/SPServer DOMAIN\user2
```

Test web api

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
...
}
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
...
}
```

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class SharePointController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("CheckOut")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(bool), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CheckOutFileAsync(string url)
    {
        var user = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.User.Identity;
        await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedAsync(user.AccessToken, async () =>
        {
            await CheckOutAsync(url);
        });
    }
    public async Task CheckOutAsync(string url)
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler, true))
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckOutFile");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://{ServerName}/_vti_bin/lists.asmx");    
            request.Content =
                new StringContent(
                    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><CheckOutFile xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\"><pageUrl>{FileUrl}</pageUrl><checkoutToLocal>true</checkoutToLocal><lastmodified /></CheckOutFile></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>",
                    Encoding.UTF8,
                    "text/xml");
            var result = await client.SendAsync(request);
        }
    }
}
```

During debbuging I see Negotiate token in request header `HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"]`.
Perhaps I need to somehow use it to call SharePoint API?

Comment: You should really consider using the extensive API when interacting with SharePoint. There is a REST API and the client-side object model (CSOM) for interacting with it.

Comment: `I'm getting a 401 return` Is Sharepoint even configured for kerberos? What are the auth settings in Sharepoint? What do you get server side on Sharepoint in the logs when client gets a 401? If you intercept the traffic, what do you see sent as authentication? (use wireshark to diagnose this)

Comment: The problem is not in Sharepoint. If SP is replaced with another api, the problem remains. I'm trying to figure out how to make a web api with a single entry point, and how to call another api from the current web api with passing win credentials?

Comment: @Dmitri Lol. 401 means server didn't like your authentication. Since what you're doing is KERBEROS you need to first and foremost confirm your SERVER is configured correctly.

Comment: I have set
`setspn -A HTTP/ServerName DOMAIN\user1
setspn -A HTTPS/ServerName DOMAIN\user1
setspn -A HTTP/ServerName:44335 DOMAIN\user1
setspn -A HTTPS/ServerName:44335 DOMAIN\user1`
In AD I set ServerName->Delegation->Trust this computer for delegation to any service (Kerberos only). For user1 the same settings.
What could I be missing?